# Fetch unique record from postgresql table in json format

Tags: json, postgresql

I am new to postgreql. I am using PG db  in my new project. I want to retrive unique records from a table in JSON format. 
I am able to write a query that fetches all unique records. However, I can't sort them by id coloum. Any Help?

**Table Rows:**

```
id      entity_id       user_id     
1       100             101
2       100             101
3       200             101
4       200             101
5       300             101
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{"id":5, "entity_id":"300", "user_id":"101"},
{"id":4, "entity_id":"200", "user_id":"101"},
{"id":2, "entity_id":"100", "user_id":"101"}
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT array_to_string (
        array( 
            select row_to_json(n1.*) FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ON(entity_id) * 
                FROM notifications
                WHERE receiver_id = _user_id ) ORDER BY entity_id, id DESC LIMIT 100 
            ) n1  
        ),', '
    ) as posts;
```

Comment: In Expected Output, `{"id":5, "entity_id":"500", "user_id":"101"}` probably you have typo and you mean 300 for `entity_id` ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT array_to_string (
    array( 
        select row_to_json(n1.*) FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ON(entity_id) * 
            FROM notifications
            WHERE receiver_id = _user_id ) ORDER BY entity_id DESC, id DESC LIMIT 100 
        ) n1  
    ),', '
) as posts;
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I added `DESC` after the entity_id

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am seeing an unrelated error in my query. Will check your change once i resolve it.